# Proving that $f(x)=x^{1/n}; (x \ge 0)$ is monotonically increasing for all positive integers $n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, induction

I am really surprised that this question hasn't already been answered here (couldn't find a similar question).

I am trying to prove that $h_n(x)=x^{1/n}\; (x \ge 0)$ is monotonically increasing for all positive integers $n using induction. The base step is immediate. For the induction step, suppose

$$h_m(x)=x^{1/m}$$

is monotonically increasing for some positive integer $m \ge 1$. This means that $h_m'(x)=\dfrac{1}{m}\cdot x^{1/m-1} = \dfrac{x^{1/m}}{x \cdot m} \ge 0$. This gives that $x^{1/m} \ge 0$. Now, we want to show that

$$h_{m+1}'(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}x^{\frac{1}{{m}+1}}= \frac{x^{\frac{1}{m+1}}}{x\cdot({m}+1)} \ge 0$$

and it would suffice to show that $x^{\frac{1}{m+1}} \ge 0$.

This is where I get stuck; I am not sure how the induction hypothesis can be used here to complete the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this fact, if $g$ is monotonically increasing, then $g\circ f$ is monotonically increasing if and only if $f$ is monotonically increasing. Now consider $g_n(x) = x^n$. Then $g_n(h_n(x)) = x$ which is monotonically increasing. Now prove by induction that $g_n(x) = x^n$ is monotonically increasing for $x\geq 0$. You will then get that since $g_n\circ h_n$ and $g_n$ are strictly monotonic, then $h_n$ must be strictly increasing as well.